# Error using math in siunitx table

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, s-column-type

I am using the S-column type from the siunitx package to align numbers horizontally in a table, which works fine when typing numbers only.
However, when I use math, I get the error

> Missing $ inserted

even though the output is displayed correctly (presumably because LaTeX adds begin-math/end-math automatically - I am using Overleaf).
Unfortunately, inserting $-signs around the expression does not solve the problem.
Does anyone have an idea as to how I solve this problem?

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lSS}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Column1} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column2}} 
        \\
    \midrule
a & 0.613 & 2.92\cdot 10^{-40}\\
b & 110.6 & $23.1\cdot 10^3$  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    % \caption{faulty table}
    \label{tab:}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong input format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=2.2e-2]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} & {\textbf{Column1}} & {\textbf{Column2}}  \\
\midrule
a & 0.613 & 2.92e-40 \\
b & 110.6 & 23.1e3  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer the centered dot, add

```
\sisetup{
  exponent-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
}
```

in the preamble.

[image]

Comment: What's the advantage of writing `exponent-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}` rather than, say, `exponent-product=\cdot`? I cannot spot a difference in the spacing around `\cdot` between `\num[exponent-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{2.92e-40}` and `\num[exponent-product=\cdot]{2.92e-40}`. Is there maybe another reason for using `\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}`?

Comment: @Mico This can be handy if numbers are processed in text mode.

Comment: Ah, got it. E.g., it's useful if the package's `detect-all` switch is set.